# How can i show multiple object records in listview

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, wrapper-class

I have 3 unrelated objects like obj1, obj2, obj3. I need to display these three object records in listview based on created date. How can i do this..?

Comment: Native way you cannot do this.

Comment: By looking at your tags I guess you already know how to do it: use a wrapper class to grab the information of different objects and use either apex:repeat or apex:dataTable to display the data based on the wrapper class. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I know using wrappers it could be done. But i don't know how to do. I googled it, in every example it showing related object results, i didn't get unrelated object records. If you give any examples it could be help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this easily with a wrapper class. Example code:

Controller:

```
public myController
{
    public List<wrapper> wrapperList {get; set;}
    public myController
    {
        List<A__c> aList = [Select Id, name From A__c];
        List<B__c> bList = [Select Id, name From B__c];
        List<C__c> cList = [Select Id, name From C__c];

        for(A__c a : aList)
        {
            wrapper w = new wrapper(a);
            wrapperList.add(a);
        }

        //Do the something for bList and cList;
    }

    public class wrapper
    {
        public A__c a;
        public B__c b;
        public C__c c;

        public wrapper(A__c a)
        {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public wrapper(B__c b)
        {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public wrapper(C__c c)
        {
            this.c = c;
        }

    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrapper" >
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet>A name</apex:facet>
        {!wrapper.a.name}
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet>B name</apex:facet>
        {!wrapper.b.name}
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet>C name</apex:facet>
        {!wrapper.c.name}
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```